# Change Password URL missing In forgot Password mail

Tags: wp-mail, password

I'm requesting Wordpress for Forgot password. I also got the mail from wordpress site.

But the change password url is missing from it.

The mail is as below :

Someone requested that the password be reset for the following account: https://www.example.com/ Username: abc@example.com If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen. To reset your password, visit the following address:

The link is not receiving in the mail.

What should be reason for it ?

Comment: No, you should receive the URL for recovery password to your email or registered email. The link will have a temporary key assigned to the user to complete the reset password.

Comment: try to reset again and you will recieve an url with the key like this one &key=8t11mMgx3jS5ZK34rvRK&login=your-user

Comment: The link is not sent in the mail

Comment: Reinstall wp-admin and wp-include

Comment: This question is already answered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/246377/missing-url-in-password-reset-email).